# Copying column data from s3 in a specific order

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Hi a vendor I use to retrieve data decided to insert a brand new column without maintaining column order to a csv file they drop in my s3 bucket, causing my daily jobs to fail. I used in alter statement to add the new column(channel_name) to the end of my table and updated my copy statement to specify the column mapping but I still get the same error message.

```
COPY myschema.chat_msg
(direction,text,channel,"user",date,sentiment,tags,filters,source_link,chatdesk_trends_message_id,chatdesk_trends_link,channel_name)
FROM 's3://myfile.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'MY CREDENTIALS
IGNOREHEADER 1
DATEFORMAT 'auto'
TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
MAXERROR 0
CSV
region as 'us-east-1'
```

The script is failing on the user column and the error reason is invalid data. The column, "channel_name" was inserted after the "channel" column causing the data to shift to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about the order of columns in your CSV and script. Was channel_name added as a last column on the CSV? Or was it added after the channel column?

If your csv has channel_name after channel, then you'll have to write columns in the same order as your csv for copy to match columns. When using copy to load from flat files, such as in an Amazon S3 bucket, their order must match the order of the source data.